# list subfolders and files of main folder with details

Tags: excel, list, vba, directory

I'm very new on programming but I'm enjoying it so far.

Maybe some tips to make a vbs fil that returns?

So far, I have this:

(but it doesn't return a counter of how many files nor separates the fields in different columns)

```
Dim fso 
Dim ObjOutFile  

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  

Set ObjOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile("OutputFiles.csv") 

ObjOutFile.WriteLine("Type,File Name,File Path") 

GetFiles("C:\Intel")  

ObjOutFile.Close  
WScript.Echo("Completed")

Function GetFiles(FolderName)  
  On Error Resume Next  
  Dim ObjFolder 
  Dim ObjSubFolders  
  Dim ObjSubFolder  
  Dim ObjFiles  
  Dim ObjFile  
  Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderName) 
  Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files  

  For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles  
    ObjOutFile.WriteLine("File," & ObjFile.Name & "," & ObjFile.Path)  
  Next  

  Set ObjSubFolders = ObjFolder.SubFolders  
  For Each ObjFolder In ObjSubFolders  
    ObjOutFile.WriteLine("Folder," & ObjFolder.Name & "," & ObjFolder.Path)  
    GetFiles(ObjFolder.Path)  
  Next  
End Function
```

Thanks in advance all you guys!
You'll have a very thankfull girl posting here! :D

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you question is?

Comment: I need help to make a vbs file that returns a list of files and subfolders of a main folder
 (what i have doesnt separates the fields in different columns)

Comment: Show us what your output looks like now and what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for pulling filenames/folders and paths.

```
Sub PullFileFolderPaths()

Dim varDirectory As Variant
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim strDirectory As String

strDirectory = "C:\Home\Preflight\"
i = 1
flag = True
varDirectory = Dir(strDirectory, vbDirectory)

While flag = True
  If varDirectory = "" Then
    flag = False
  Else
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = varDirectory
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = strDirectory + varDirectory
    'returns the next file or directory in the path
    varDirectory = Dir
    i = i + 1
End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Bill, thank you so much for the help!! now im adapting this to the .vbs file :S